# ¿Cómo bloquear los días pasados en calendario de input date?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando validar que no se pueda seleccionar los días pasados de un calendario de **input date**.Lo he hecho con **jquery** antes, pero me pasa fallando por temas de librerías y me bloquea otras funciones.Por eso he decidido hacerlo sólo con **javascript** puro y usando **input date**, pero todas las soluciones que he encontrado con **input date**, usan atributo *min* con una fecha por defecto, pero necesito usarlo que sea dinámico, que tome la fecha actual tal como se hace con **jquery** pero esta vez usando sólo **jasvacript**.

Mi Código:

```js
var fecha = new Date();
var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var _mes = fecha.getMonth(); //viene con valores de 0 al 11
_mes = _mes + 1; //ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
if (_mes < 10) //ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
{
  var mes = "0" + _mes;
} else {
  var mes = _mes.toString;
}
document.getElementById("fechaReserva").min = anio + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prueaba Key Up</title>

</head>

<body>

  <form onsubmit="validar();">
    <label>
Fecha Inicio
</label>
    <input type="date" id="fechaReserva" min="2019-09-01" name="txtfechainicio"><br>
    <hr>


  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

No he encontrado la manera para que funcione tomando la fecha actual y no una por defecto ingresada en *min*.

Utilizando la solución que me brindaron, me muestra error la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que navegador y versión estas usando? Porque yo veo que funciona bien

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas asignando el valor al atributo `min` de manera inorrecta, debes establecer el valor con el método `setAttribute` de la siguiente manera;

`document.getElementById("fechaReserva").setAttribute('min',fecha_minimo);`

**Ejemplo:**

```js
var fecha = new Date();
var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var _mes = fecha.getMonth(); //viene con valores de 0 al 11
_mes = _mes + 1; //ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
if (_mes < 10) //ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
{
  var mes = "0" + _mes;
} else {
  var mes = _mes.toString;
}

let fecha_minimo = anio + '-' + mes + '-' + dia; // Nueva variable

document.getElementById("fechaReserva").setAttribute('min',fecha_minimo);
```

```html
   <form onsubmit="validar();">
   <label>
       Fecha Inicio
   </label>
   <input type="date" id="fechaReserva" name="txtfechainicio"><br>
   <hr>
</form>
```

Como podrás observar he agregado la variable `fecha_minimo` para en ella almacenar la fecha concatenada, posteriormente asignamos el atributo `min` el valor de la variable, así el atributo `min` se establece de  manera dinámica.

**coloquemos un poquito de esteroides al ejemplo;**

Vamos a quitar las flechas de subir y bajar del campo utilizando CSS y evitemos que el usuario use las flechas del teclado;

```js
    var fecha = new Date();
    var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
    var dia = fecha.getDate();
    var _mes = fecha.getMonth(); //viene con valores de 0 al 11
    _mes = _mes + 1; //ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
    if (_mes < 10) //ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
    {
        var mes = "0" + _mes;
    } else {
        var mes = _mes.toString;
    }

    var fecha_minimo = anio + '-' + mes + '-' + dia; // Nueva variable

    document.getElementById("fechaReserva").setAttribute('min', fecha_minimo);
```

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <form onsubmit="validar();">
        <label>
            Fecha Inicio
        </label>
        <input type="date" id="fechaReserva" onkeydown="return false" name="txtfechainicio"><br>
        <hr>
    </form>
```

Comment: hola veo que en el ejemplo que dejaste funciona, pero copie el código y lo reemplace en mi ejemplo y no me funciona.Le agregaste algo mas que no se esté visualizando en esta plataforma?

Comment: @SimónPereiraVigouroux solo he agregado la variable `fecha_minimo` y cambie la linea de la asignación del atributo. Quizás no lo especifique, modifico para tenerlo mas claro.

Comment: @Marcos eso es correcto, se puede pulir mas, de requerirse esto ya seria otra pregunta, no? de todas maneras lo colocare.

Comment: será problema de navegador? , porque copie el codigo exactamente igual y elimine los temorales y todo y sigue sin funcionar :P me permite seleccionar cualquier fecha.Incluso le quite el onsubmit y nada

Comment: Esta interesante lo que te sucede @SimónPereiraVigouroux , he probado el ejemplo fuera y no tengo problemas inclusive en `Microsoft Edge`

Comment: voy a agregar una imagen en mi publicación ya que en la consola me indica null en setAttribute

Comment: ya agregue el error al final de mi publicación

Comment: Coloca tu etiqueta `script` justo después del cierre de la etiqueta `body` porque al parecer tienes el `script` en tu `head`

Comment: si ese es el problema, gracias. Por qué en estos casos el script se agrega despues del body y no entre las etiquetas head?

Comment: @SimónPereiraVigouroux en resumen lo que pasa es que el DOM no esta cargado cuando se ejecuta el `script` si lo tienes en el `head`, a menos que esperes a que se cargue el `DOM` para ejecutar el `script` con el famoso `documentReady` que lo usamos mucho con `Jquery` pero hoy día es común ver esto.

Comment: a ok entiendo por que en jquery yo he utilizado los script antes de la etiqueta de cierre de body y funcionan tambien pero en javascript puro no sabia que se podia ingresar despues de la etiqueta de cierre de body. mil gracias

Answer (score 3):

Una solución más sencilla utilizando el formato ISO de la fecha.
Se utiliza un `split()` para dividir el tiempo y la fecha `"2000-00-01T00:00:00"`

 Tomando solo la parte izquierda con el `split("T")[0]`.

```js
fechaReserva.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="date" id="fechaReserva" name="txtfechainicio">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Hola buenas una consulta, si quisiera bloquear la fecha pero en 2 campos input que deberia poner? ya que agregue otro script  y otro input y no me funcionó

Comment: Ocupas repetir el mismo proceso en el otro input,como por ejemplo fechaReserva2, podrías hacerlo para varios generando un método en común y de alguna manera distinguir los input que quieres que compartan este proceso.

Comment: si lo hice, copie el mismo script abajo del anterior y le puse otro id y se lo agregue al otro input, pero solo funciona el primer input

Comment: cual podria ser el problema? en la consola me dice que la variable fecha_minimo ya esta declarada, me imagino que debo cambiar el nombre?

Comment: Si eso era lo solucione gracias