# bloquear dias del calendario input reactjs

Tags: reactjs

buen dia, como hago para bloquear ciertos dias del calendario en un input reactjs

```html
<input type="date" className="form-control" placeholder="juan" name="pais" />
```

Comment: Esta respuesta te puede servir: [¿Cómo bloquear los días pasados en calendario de input date?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291776/)

Comment: pero en reactjs como seria, ademas seria dias puntuales no dias pasados.

Comment: Es una guía en JS Vanilla, podrías consultarla y según avances, [edit] tu pregunta con lo que has intentado.